# Vue js 3 - My Json or Object tree viewer have a duplicate key bug when multiple values are similar

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tree, vuejs3, treeview

I have a problem with this code: I'm trying to make a tree viewer from a object and it work great until when a value is exactly the same as another value it clone de key and it replace the same key where the value is the same.

On CodePen: https://codepen.io/onigetoc/pen/rNPeQag?editors=1010

**This object:**

```
[
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "delectus aut autem",
        "description": "delectus aut autem"
    },
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
        "description": "et porro tempora"
    },
]
```

**Give me in my tree view that:**

```
[-]
userId:1
userId:1
title:delectus aut autem
title:delectus aut autem
[-]
userId:1
id:2
title:quis ut nam facilis et officia qui
description:et porro tempora
```

We can see that the keys **userId** and **title** are duplicated because they have the same values.
The second part is ok because there's no identical values.

**HTML part:**

```
<!-- item template -->
<script type="text/x-template" id="item-template">
  <li>
    <span :class="{bold: isFolder}" @click="toggle">
      <span class="key" v-if="!isFolder" @click="toggleKey">{{ key }}:</span>
      <span class="value" v-if="!isFolder">{{ value }}</span>
      <span v-if="isFolder">[{{ isOpen ? '-' : '+' }}]</span>
    </span>
    <ul v-show="isOpen" v-if="isFolder">
      <tree-item
        class="item"
        v-for="(child, index) in item"
        :key="index"
        :item="child"
      ></tree-item>
    </ul>
  </li>
</script>

<p>(You can double click on an item to turn it into a folder.)</p>

<!-- the demo root element -->
<ul class="view-list" id="connect-list">
  <tree-item class="item" :item="treeData" @make-folder="makeFolder" @add-item="addItem"></tree-item>
</ul>
```

**Javascript part:**

```
<!-- demo data -->
// https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
var treeData = [
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "delectus aut autem",
        "description": "delectus aut autem"
    },
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
        "description": "et porro tempora"
    },
];

const app = Vue.createApp({
  data: function() {
    return {
      treeData: treeData
    }
  },

methods: {
  makeFolder: function(item) {
    Vue.set(item, 'newFolder', {});
    this.addItem(item.newFolder);
  },
  addItem: function(item) {
    Vue.set(item, 'newItem', 'new stuff');
  }
}
})

app.component("tree-item", {
  template: '#item-template',
  props: {
    item: Object
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      isOpen: true // default was false
    };
  },
  computed: {
    isFolder: function() {
      return typeof this.item === 'object' && this.item !== null;
    },
    key: function() {
      if (typeof this.item === 'object' && this.item !== null) {
        return '';
      } else {
        return Object.keys(this.$parent.item).find(key => this.$parent.item[key] === this.item);
      }
    },
    value: function() {
      if (typeof this.item === 'object' && this.item !== null) {
        return '';
      } else {
        return this.item;
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function() {
      if (this.isFolder) {
        this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
      }
    },
    toggleKey: function(event) {
      event.target.classList.toggle("bgcolor");
    }
  }
})

  app.mount('#connect-list')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `Object.keys(this.$parent.item).find(key => this.$parent.item[key] === this.item);` will find the first key with a matching `value`

Simple fix really, you need to pass the "index" as a prop (since the index in an object is a string, and `item` is an Object in `tree-item`)

I use `name` as the prop, but I don't really like that :p can't think of a better name for this prop - but, that's not really something to worry about

```
  <tree-item
    class="item"
    v-for="(child, index) in item"
    :key="index"
    :name="index"
    :item="child"
  ></tree-item>
```

note: keep the `:key="index"` as that is vital for the `v-for`

and return `this.name` in the `key:` computed

```
key: function() {
      if (typeof this.item === 'object' && this.item !== null) {
        return '';
      } else {
        return this.name;
      }
    },
```

Comment: Did you test it? because it doesn't work. If you make a version work can you save your version temporally if you want with the code here to help other who would need it?

Comment: @Gino yes, I did test it. I always test code before I post it ... did you add the `name` prop to your tree-item component? - i.e. add it like `props: { item: Object, name: String },`

Comment: @Gino - code in that link seems to work as required?

Comment: I fixed it and i find out because i missed something about the prop and it's ok now